# test if a method is called by mocking another method using moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Given a class that has method SplitList and Update. Update is being called from SplitList.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void SplitList(ref IList<Type> objList)
    {
        IList<Type> SplitA = objList.Where(c=>c.currency == "USD").ToList();
        IList<Type> SplitB = objList.Where(c=>c.currency == "GBR").ToList();

        if(SplitA.Count() > 0)
        {
            Update(ref SplitA);
        }

        if(SplitB.Count() > 0)
        {
            Update(ref SplitB);
        }
    }
}
```

What i want to test is when I call SplitList method, how many times is Update being called.
I mean if both if being called, or one, or none.
Need to test the boundary conditions for that method.

How i have proceeded for it is,

```
class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    void TestSplitList()
    {
        Mock<BaseClass> mock = new Mock<BaseClass>();
        mock.Setup(m=>m.Update(ref List)).Verifiable();
        mock.Object.SplitList(ref List);
        mock.Verify(m=>m.Update(ref List), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
}
```

This code is giving me error as,
**Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: m => m.Update(.List)**

Can anyone please help with this ?

Comment: Show us the Update method implementation

Comment: public virtual Update(IList<Type> updateList)
    {
     int count = 0;
     foreach(Type objType in updateList)
     {
      objType.OrderNo = count++;
     }
     return updateList;
    } Something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `SplitList` method `virtual`? (Since your posted code might be not identical to the codebase.) In that case, Moq will override it and your `Update` will not be called. You can either make it non-virtual, or have Moq call it by adding this line:

```
mock.CallBase = true;
```

If you choose this approach, beware that *all* methods will "CallBase" (if no expectation overrides the member).

Update:
You're passing a different list to `Update` method in `SplitList` implementation. The parameter is `objList`, then you create a different lists (`SplitA` and `SplitB`) and pass one them to `Update` method. Since `SplitA` (or `SplitB`) `!=` `objList`, the test fails.

<strike>Do you really have to use `ref` here? If you remove it, the code will be simpler and the tests will pass.</strike> The lists will still be different without ref, sorry I missed that. I think you might need to change your logic to allow better testing..

Comment: Yes SplitList method is virtual. But i tried adding CallBase. It still is giving same error. What i think is that, when i am calling the actual method by mock object, its not giving call to the internal methods.

Comment: @user3667853 Yes, that is what I mean by "Moq will override it". CallBase would have fixed it but you have a different problem, please see my update.

Comment: I updated the base class code. removed the ref implementation and returned the list. Still facing the same issue. As now i think i am passing the list as normal variable but inside the SplitList method, its splitting in 2 diff lists, and calling the update method using these new lists. Maybe thats why mock call is not able to capture if update is called or not.

Comment: Could you provide an updated repro case ? Plus : 

 - What is the visibility of the `Update` method ?
 - Are you relying on `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Mocking a class with a virtual method will allow you to verify the method. You can also use `CallBase` to invoke the actual method (`Update`) at the same time.

Assuming the following code (given that your posted Update does not contain a `ref` parameter, I've removed the unnecessary ref from Split):

```
public class Type
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
}
public class BaseClass
{
    // w.r.t ref, do you mean to reassign objList to the filtered lists?
    public void SplitList(ref IList<Type> objList)
    {
        var SplitA = objList.Where(c => c.currency == "USD").ToList();
        var SplitB = objList.Where(c => c.currency == "GBR").ToList();

        if (SplitA.Count() > 0)
        {
            Update(SplitA);
        }

        if (SplitB.Count() > 0)
        {
            Update(SplitB);
        }
    }

    public virtual IList<Type> Update(IList<Type> updateList)
    {
        int count = 0; 
        foreach (Type objType in updateList)
        {
            objType.OrderNo = count++;
        } 
        return updateList;
    }
}
```

This Unit test demonstrates that the virtual `Update` method can be verified as well as being invoked. If you choose *not* to use `CallBase`, then the Unit Test will need to be adjusted as the mutation to the elements in the list will not happen.

```
[Test]
public void TestSplitList()
{
    var mock = new Mock<BaseClass>();
    mock.CallBase = true; // This will ensure the actual Update also gets called
    IList<Type> fakeTypes = new List<Type>
                        {
                            new Type {currency = "GBR"},
                            new Type {currency = "GBR", OrderNo = 100},
                            new Type {currency = "JPY", OrderNo = 55}
                        };

    mock.Object.SplitList(ref fakeTypes);

    mock.Verify(m => m.Update(It.IsAny<IList<Type>>()), Times.Exactly(1));
    mock.Verify(m => m.Update(It.Is<IList<Type>>(x => x.Any(y => y.currency == "GBR") 
                && x.Count == 2)), Times.Exactly(1));
    mock.Verify(m => m.Update(It.Is<IList<Type>>(
        x => x.Any(y => y.currency == "JPY"))), Times.Never);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, fakeTypes.Count, "List itself must not have changed");

    // These tests show the effect of the actual `Update` method
    Assert.IsTrue(fakeTypes.Any(t => t.OrderNo == 0 && t.currency == "GBR"), 
       "GBR must be ordered");
    Assert.IsTrue(fakeTypes.Any(t => t.OrderNo == 1 && t.currency == "GBR"), 
       "GBR must be ordered");
    Assert.IsFalse(fakeTypes.Any(t => t.OrderNo == 100 && t.currency == "GBR"), 
       "GBR must be ordered");
    Assert.IsTrue(fakeTypes.Any(t => t.OrderNo == 55 && t.currency == "JPY"), 
       "JPY must not be ordered");
}
```

Note: The use of `ref` on the `List` parameters is unnecessary in your current code implementation. Because you are directly mutating the objects in the list, these changes will be visible to all collections referencing these items. Also, you aren't changing the list itself (just the elements in it), so you won't need to either make the `Update` param `ref`, nor return it from `Update`.